# How to use file paths when accessing git hub code from different computer?

Tags: python, git, github, dataset

I am working on a Python project from two different computers (Windows and Mac).
The project uses a locally stored dataset. Naturally, the paths to the dataset are different on each computer.

**Path on Windows:**

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\Python\Projects\dataset.csv")
```

**Path on MAC:**

```
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/JohnSmith/Python/Projects/dataset.csv")
```

When I commit changes from the Windows machine the code won't work on Mac until I change the file path. This creates a problem because the path has to be changed every time I open the code with a different machine. Is there a way to void this?

I realize that storing the dataset online is one way to solve this but some of the datasets are more than 500mb. I don't know where I can store and use them without having to download.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways to solve this:

1. Store the data set relative to the root of the repository and refer to it using a relative path (e.g., `./dataset.csv`).  You'd want to make sure that if this path is in within your repository that you add the file to `.gitignore`.
2. Use a configuration file (which is ignored by Git) to choose the path to use on a given system.  Then, create different config files on different systems.

Note that you can use `./` or `../` in paths on Windows and those work fine, since Windows understands `.`, `..`, and slashes in paths.